# I use an infinite loop to execute the code. As time goes on, will this happen, such as stack overflow?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I use python selenium to automate a website, but I use an infinite loop to execute the code. As time goes on, will this happen, such as stack overflow?

I used selenium in python and used infinite loops in my code. I didn't have any problems at first, but as the time went by I got the following error.what should I do?

```
[13988:1284:0501/110015.734:ERROR:latency_info.cc(164)] Display::DrawAndSwap, 
LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.
```

Here is the code

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
import time
n=1
driver=webdriver.Chrome('F:\pythonjiaoben\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('this is my web url')

def is_text(a):
    try:
        elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text(a)
        return True
    except:
        return False
def is_shuaxin():
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p")
        elem=elem.text
        if re.match(r'您点击',elem):
            return True
        else:
            return False 
    except:
        print("我错了")
        return False
def is_chakan(sa):
    try:
        elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/p")
        elem=elem.text
        if re.findall(r'%s' % sa,elem):
            return True

        else:
            return False 
    except:
        return False

def gongji():
    while(n>0):
        if is_text("地狱之门[永恒]"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("地狱之门[永恒]")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

        if is_text("进入世界"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("进入世界")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_text("加曼迪拉") and is_chakan("横在炽热之路"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("加曼迪拉")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("目标已经不在了"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("返回游戏")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("火羽山的三个守护者之一"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("攻击")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("准备"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("察看")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("横在炽热之路"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("察看")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("公墓"):
            fuhuo()
        if is_shuaxin():
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("返回游戏")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        else:
            fuhuo()

def fuhuo():
    while(n>0):
        if is_chakan("超生"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("信徒路(恢复)")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("大理石地面和纯白的廊柱"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("恢复")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("南广场"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("广场(传送)")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("牧师把手放在你的伤口上"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("环顾四周")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("广场(传送)")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

        if is_chakan("南集市"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("集市(拍卖)")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
        if is_chakan("南铁匠铺"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("铁匠铺(修理)")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("装备凝练"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("修理")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("修理全部"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("*修理全部")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            break
        if is_shuaxin():
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("返回游戏")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        break
    chuansong()

def chuansong():
    while(n>0):
        if is_chakan("你花费"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("返回游戏")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("通灵坐骑装备合成"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("地图")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("完成勇者之心任务"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("时空转移")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("快速回城"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("天火岩")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_chakan("挂机地图"):
            if is_text("开始挂机"):
                elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("开始挂机")
                elem.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
            else:
                if is_text("返回游戏"):
                    elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("返回游戏")
                    elem.click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    break
        if is_chakan("横在炽热之路上"):
            elem=driver.find_element_by_link_text("挂机")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        if is_shuaxin():
            elem=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("返回游戏")
            elem.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        break
gongji()
```

Well, I know the code is poorly written and I'm still learning it initially, so if you have any better way to modify the code, please point it out below. thank you very much!

Comment: A regular loop doesn't cause overflow errors. Recursion would, but I'm not seeing that in the code

Comment: @cricket_007  
Does the gongji() function execute an infinite loop that will cause this problem?

Comment: Is it calling itself? Doesn't look like it to me

Answer (score 0):

If everything is in python, there shouldn't be any issues with stack/buffer overflow. Keeping the infinite loop should be alright.

However, it is best you use a profiling tool, or just monitor the resources used by your process from start till end.

Comment: Yes, but it is not as likely since python is type safe for example, hence i used the word 'shouldn't'

Comment: Type safety has nothing to do with stack or buffer overflow

Comment: It sure does. Of course, it is not entirely immune to buffer overflow [see here](https://books.google.com/books?id=fDxg1W3eT2gC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=type+buffer+overflow&source=bl&ots=e8-YfyBolD&sig=lmpQSHiq1Sv71Le60DEY4Lhzo4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtp5rk3-PaAhURON8KHaU8DO4Q6AEIvQEwEg#v=onepage&q=type-safety&f=false)